# Can Handlebars set a javascript variable to null?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars to define some JavaScript variables using information I'm pulling from an API. Like this:

```
var userState = {{user.user_state.value}};
```

This generally works great unless `user.user_state.value` is `null`, in which case it gets compiled like this:

```
var userStateNow = ;
```

This is making the app I'm writing crash. I've tried using `try`/`catch`, but it didn't help. Any other ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Using Handlerbars to generate JavaScript source code seems really awkward...

Comment: ...but I'm not entirely sure why. I mean, it's a templating tool. Sometimes, you need to generate code with templates. So hey. :-)

Comment: If it's information that you're getting from an API is there any reason you can't pull from it within your JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1):

You can register your own helper that does an explicit `null` check:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('nullsafe', function(value) {
  return value === null ? "null" : value;
});
```

then

```
var userState = {{nullsafe user.user_state.value}};
```

but my guess is that would only push the problem back one level. What if the value is the string `"foo"`, for instance? Your result will be

```
var userState = foo;
```

not

```
var userState = "foo";
```

You could use `JSON.stringify` to output values that will always be valid JavaScript values:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(value) {
  return JSON.stringify(value);
});
```

then

```
var userState = {{json user.user_state.value}};
```

That would handle `null`, my string example, and a couple of other cases; but not `undefined`. We could tweak it:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('jsout', function(value) {
  return value === undefined ? "undefined" : JSON.stringify(value);
});
```

then

```
var userState = {{jsout user.user_state.value}};
```

And so on until you have something that works for your use case.